# Es posible guardar en un useState un array de un json?

Tags: reactjs

Me explico, estoy recibiendo un Json con el siguiente fetch:

```
  function LoadActivity() {
    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setActivity(data.data[0].nombre)); //console.log(data.data[0])
  }

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    LoadActivity();
  }, []);
```

El json llega asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo general, lo normal y lo mas sencillo es que el `json` directamente traiga el `array` en si, en vez de que un dato del `json` contenga el `array`.

Mi pregunta es, es posible acceder al array que hay en un dato json? Lo intenté de vcarias maneras pero solamente logro traerme uno por uno.

Por ejemplo, para traerme la posicion 0 del Array, tengo que hacer

```
...
.then((data) =>console.log(data.data[0].nombre))
```

Y ésto lo hago asi ya que `data.data[0]` me tira errores

> react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, nombre, correo}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Y cuando hago el mapeo en el `return`

> Activity.jsx:17 Uncaught TypeError: activity.map is not a function
> at Activity

Pero bueno, mi consulta es esa, si hay alguna manera de acceder al array posicion por posicion, y no por dato especifico (nombre, correo, id)

Osea, yo deberia poder hacer un `.then((data) => setActivity(data.data))`, y luego en el return, pueda hacer un `map()` de cada uno

Asi..

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>{activity}</h1>
      {
        activity?.map((cliente, index) =>        
            <div>
                <h2>{cliente.data[index].nombre}</h2>
                <h2>{cliente.correo[index].correo}</h2>
                <h2>{cliente.id[index].id}</h2>
            </div>
        )
      }
      <button>Cargar Más</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Version 2:

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cliente</h1>
      {
        activity?.length && activity.map((cliente, index) =>        
            <div>
                <h2>{cliente.data[index].nombre}</h2>
                <h2>{cliente.data[index].correo}</h2>
                <h2>{cliente.data[index].id}</h2>
            </div>
        )
      }
      <button>Cargar Más</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Error que muestra en consola:

> react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the
>  component:
> at Activity (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97:82)
> at App
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: Esta bien el error, vos estas queriendo hacer un map, que es una funcion iteradora para hacerla sobre arrays. Pero vos no estas guardando el array ``data`` en ``activity`` sino que estas guardando el primer elemento como un objeto, por eso no podes iterar. Esta bien setear (data.data) en el state. Finalmente, para que el map funcione correctamente, deberias hacer algo como ``activity?.length && activity.map((cliente...`` para que se ejecute cuando el array tenga datos

Comment: Ahi actualicé con lo que usted me dijo

Answer (score 0):

Bien, al parecer estaba recibiendo el json como un objeto y no como un array, es por eso que no podia mapearlo. Por lo que tenia que ubicar la respuesta en un array cuando lo guardaba...

```
  function LoadActivity() {
      fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/listarClientes")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setActivity([data])
      });
```